# Why Bridge edge loops don't fit the same number of vertex or the closer one

Tags: edges, loop

I'm doing this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/DqBOva04lcE?t=690

and at the 11:30 I need to add a circle to use "Bridge edge loops" to connect every vertex.

[image]

As you can see there is 162 vertex, so, I add a circle with 162 vertex...

[image]

Then I select the verxtes of the gear and (try to) use Bridge edge loops...

[image]

I followed the tutorial, step by step, almost 5 times in a row (just this day!), and always get the same result.

In the next gift I show you the situation, and some fix that I found, but not the most convenient.

(after use bridge edge loops, rotate the circle 180d over X, and some degrees over Z)

[image]

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello :). This usually happens when the circle has normals pointing in the wrong direction. When you add it, just go *Mesh > Normals > Flip* and it should work better.

Comment: Negative @JachymMichal it doesn't work. I Added the circle, do as you say, and keep the same behavior.